# condition always returns false

Tags: bash, shell, githooks

Below is my pre-commit git hoook

```
#!/bin/bash

....
# if git diff -U0 "$FILE_PATH" | grep -iq 'todo'; # Double quoting $FILE_PATH doesnt' change anything
if git diff -U0 $FILE_PATH | grep -iq 'todo';
then
    echo $FILE_PATH ' -> Contains TODO'
    exit 1

else
    echo 'nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo'
fi
```

I'm always getting the `noooooooooooooooooooo` message, however the command below, tried directly on my terminal, works well:

```
git diff -U0 my/file/path.php | grep -iq 'todo' && echo 'true' || echo 'false'
```

Output

```
true
```

**UPDATE**

When running `bash .git/hooks/pre-commit` it works, very strange!!

**FYI**

I don't know if it's an important information but .git/hooks/pre-commit is a symbolik link

Comment: double quote `$FILE_PATH` and try again...

Comment: @Jahid doesn't change the result, and I'm always getting `true` when trying from my terminal

Comment: How are you running the script and with who? What does `git diff -U0 $FILE_PATH | grep -i 'todo'` return when run on it's own in the script? How about just `git diff -U0 $FILE_PATH` ?

Comment: @123 very interesting actually, when running the script `bash my_script` it works. But doesn't work when running `git commit`

Comment: Is the `$FILE_PATH` absolute?

Comment: @Ian2thedv it's not, I just tried with an absolute  path and gave exactly the same thing

Comment: Are you sure the command `git diff -U0 "$FILE_PATH"` actually works before piping it to grep? Just print to screen or write to file and confirm that it actually contains the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your pipe does not return status 0. To verify that this is the case (and not the way you write your compound statement), you could rewrite it as

```
git diff -U0 "$FILE_PATH" | grep -iq 'todo'
grep_status=$?
echo grep status is $grep_status
if (( grep_status == 0 ))
then
  echo contains todo
else
  echo no
fi
```

I also noticed that your code contains an unnecessary semicolon in the `if` line. I first thought that this semicolon might cause the weird behaviour, but at least on my `bash`, where I tried your code, it does not seem to do any harm. Still,  I would remove it for the safe side.

Comment: that always gives `grep status is 1`

Comment: Well, this means that the word *todo* has not be found in the output of `git diff`. If you think that this can't be the case, direct a copy of the git output to stdout, for instance like this: `git diff -U0 "$FILE_PATH" | tee tmp$$; grep -iq todo tmp$$`